# Map cartesian to circular coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, math, geometry

Hey Stackoverflow community,
I need you help with an issue I can not get my head around... . So thank you for any support. :)

I would like to code a 'simple bubble level'. However the positioning of the bubble itself seems to be a bit trickier than thought. The result should be similar to how the scribble below looks like.
[image: Bubble level example]

The question is **how do I calculate the red & blue coordinate points** inside the circular view? In that way converting the input such as `-2 | 2` and `2 | 3` to on-screen drawable coordinated like `-1.4 | 1.4` and `1.6 | 2.5` respectively (based on the drawing below ;) ).

Initially I tried to go with basic trigonometry, but everything ended up in wrong results... .

```
let angleInRad = atan2(slope.y, slope.x)
let distance = sqrt(pow(slope.x, 2) + pow(slope.y, 2))
let x = distance * cos(angleInRad)
let y = distance * sin(angleInRad)
```

Than I continued with polar coordinates but those resulted in similar unwanted results... .

Comment: I don’t understand -2|2 and 2|3. Seems the the second number  is the circle, but what is the first ?

Comment: Hey @PtitXav, those should be just coordinates which are than mapped to a circular layout rather than a "squared" one. So we still have two axis (x increasing to the right, y increasing to the top) which however shouldn't be connected "with straight" lines, but in a circular shape.

Comment: i understand that the second coordinate is the distance from the center. But in your example I don’t understand where the -2 and 2 means as angle : what is the origin of angle (in radians) ?

Answer (score 0):

The atan2 function should be atan2(y, x).

Comment: Thanks for the point, seems like I just used a wrong 'look up' before: https://www.alphacodingskills.com/swift/notes/swift-math-atan2.php vs https://www.alphacodingskills.com/swift/notes/swift-math-atan2.php.

However this does not help to much, as the result is still off... .